# Анимация setVisibility GONE/VISIBLE

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Как сделать, чтобы при скрытии нескольких View-элементов, находящихся рядом в LinearLayout было так:

1. View-элементы одновременно плавно выцветают.
2. Все, что было под ними, плавно сдвигается вверх на их место.

И аналогично для `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Пробовал использовать `animateLayoutChanges="true"` - не срабатывает.

---

**UPD:**
`animateLayoutChanges="true"` не срабатывало только в `ScrollView`, после перенесения этого атрибута в `LinearLayout` все получилось.

Comment: лейаут свой покажите

Comment: `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` в `LinearLayout` тоже работает. Я и не знал. Сейчас внизу ответ дополню.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задачу можно решить с помощью [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html). Возьмем для примера `LinearLayout` с тремя элементами:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ru.jollydroid.propertyanimationdisappearance.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="One"
        android:textColor="#00ffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Two"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Three"
        android:textColor="#ffff00"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Как бы мы сделали без анимации?

```
two.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Что это дает? Элемент `two` исчезает, элемент `three` смещается наверх на место `two`.

Какая нам нужна анимация? Сначала у элемента `two` плавно уменьшить прозрачность, затем элемент `three` плавно сместить наверх на высоту элемента `two`. Так и запишем:

```
void stepOne() {
    two.animate()
            .setDuration(500)
            .alpha(0)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    stepTwo();
                }
            });
}

void stepTwo() {
    three.animate()
            .setDuration(500)
            .translationY(-binding.two.getHeight())
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    stepThree();
                }
            });
}

/*
нужно в конце анимаци вернуть свойства в исходное состояние, но так,
чтобы взаимное расположение осталось неизменным
 */
void stepThree() {
    // отключаем лиснеры, на всякий случай, чтобы при следующей анимации неожиданно не сработал
    three.animate().setListener(null);
    two.animate().setListener(null);
    // сводим задачу к предыдущей
    two.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // возвращаем свойства в исходное состояние
    three.setTranslationY(0);
    binding.two.setAlpha(1);
}
```

При наступлении события надо запустить `stepOne()`.

Надо ли чистить последствия анимации на третьем шаге - решать вам. Если это разовый эффект, то надо, чтобы дальнейшая работа с интерфейсом не была неожиданной, потому что, например, элемент `three` так и останется смещенным относительно своего исходного положения. Если же все поведение интерфейса будет построено на анимации, то не надо, чтобы появление элемента `two` обратно можно было сделать аналогично исчезновению.

Про эту анимацию была статья в блоге:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html

Еще один пример использования этй же анимации есть в моей статье: http://jollydroid.ru/notebook/2016-04-05-Property-Animation-Rotation.html

Comment: А лисенеры обязательно отключать?

Comment: Если нет необходимости оставить, я бы отключал, из общегигиенических соображений. Вы потом повесите еще какую-то анимацию, забытые лиснеры будут иногда срабатывать, вы потратите время на исправление. Зачем оно?

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно использовать `animateLayoutChanges="true"`. Чтобы оно работало нужно использовать `linearLayout.addView(view)` чтобы добавить вьюшку с анимацией и чтобы удалить `linearlayout.removeView(view)`.

В разделе "Курсы" есть статья: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Comment: C `setVisibility()` оно, оказывается, тоже работает, только что сделал демку. https://github.com/tseglevskiy/AnimateLayoutChangesDemo

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь в виду. На самом деле это логично так как по сути тут тоже происходит удаление вьюшки.

Comment: Большое спасибо, после того, как перенес этот параметр из scrollview во внутрь, в linearlayout, заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Второй способ решения этой задачи - поменять LinearLayout на [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). Тогда можно исчезновение и появление сделать с помощью [RecyclerView.ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html) - написать свой или взять готовый. Тогда получится универсальное решение, которое одинаково красиво покажет исчезновение или появление любого количества элементов.

Аниматор можно оставить [стандартный](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator.html) или найти в сторонней библиотеке:
https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: `RecyclerView` уже имеет анимации плавного исчезовения и плавного смещения оставшихся айтемов при удалении одного из них (метод `notifyItemRemoved()` адаптера), дополнительный аниматор подключать не нужно для этого.