# Как сделать анимированный выпадающий список в android?

Tags: android, android-studio, анимация

Есть на layout несколько кнопок расположенных вертикально, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на одну из кнопок вылезала дополнительная информация. Повторное нажатие вызвало бы такое плавное исчезновение этой дополнительно информации. Пробовал использовать анимацию scale, но она не сдвигает остальные элементы, также пробовал ExpandableListView, но это список, поэтому не знаю логично ли его здесь использовать, ведь мне список не нужен, плюс не знаю как изменять анимацию ExpandableListView.

---

Пример того, что должно получится в итоге:

[image: Исходная позиция]
[image: Конечная позиция]

Comment: чем у вас сам список формируется? RecyclerView, или это заранее созданный layout?

Comment: На картинках пример, который я встретил в другом приложении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть несколько рецептов, как сделать анимацию появления-исчезновения элементов, выберите подходящий:
[Анимация setVisibility GONE/VISIBLE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612991/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-setvisibility-gone-visible)

Другой способ - сделать RecyclerView с элементами двух типов, тогда элементы-заголовки и элементы-подробности будут самостоятельными элементами в списке. При необходимости раскрыть нужно будет добавить в список элемент с деталями, а анимацию сделает аниматор от RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так же воспользоваться библиотекой [Expandable Layout](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout)

Добавляется в одну строчку.
Использование тоже не очень сложное.